# Paginação com AngularJS e WebAPI

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Preciso fazer uma paginação usando `AngularJS`. Bem, fiz uma controller para popular uma `Table HTML`. Isso agora tá funcionando. O meu próximo passo será paginar essa table. Peguei um exemplo na internet, só que o exemplo o cara faz um for de 1 até 1000 e sai paginando. No meu caso é diferente, eu recebo um `JSON` do meu `REST` e necessito paginar isso, separa em bloco de 10, como eu recebo 40 registros serializados, daria 4 páginas de 10. Fiz uma controller.js somente para isso, é o certo, para separar bem. Cada caso um caso. Abaixo a minha controller:

```
var pagina = angular.module('app', []);

pagina.controller("PaginacaoController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.filteredTodos = []
   , $scope.currentPage = 1
   , $scope.numPerPage = 10
   , $scope.maxSize = 5;

    $scope.makePagina = function () {
        $scope.pagina = [];
        for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            $scope.pagina.push({ text: "Teste " + i, done: false });
        }
    };

    $scope.makePagina();

    $scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function () {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
        , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

        $scope.filteredPagina = $scope.pagina.slice(begin, end);
    });

})
```

Tenho duas dúvidas aí:

1) Na segunda function(), a do **for**, creio que eu devo colocar um data e pegar o data.items(dessa forma eu pego o `JSON` para popular a table), mas `data.items.length`, não funfa, comigo deu erro.

2) Veja que `$scope.numPerPage` está fixo em 10, mas nesse caso não sei quantos registros vêm e a paginação deveria ser dinâmica.

Abaixo a minha view, que hoje funciona para popular a table:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Tipo Contato Operadora</h2>

<div data-ng-controller="TipoContatoOperadoraController">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Lista de Tipo de Contato das Operadoras</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                        <strong>{{erro}}</strong>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Cod. Tipo Contato</th>
                                    <th>Nome Tipo Contato</th>
                                    <th>Ind. Tipo Contato</th>
                                    <th>Data Atualização</th>
                                    <th>Cod. Usuário</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr data-ng-repeat="lista in listaTipoContatoOperadora">
                                    <td>{{ lista.id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ lista.nome }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ lista.tipoContato }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ lista.dataUltimaAtualizacao }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ lista.loginUltimaAtualizacao }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***EDIÇÃO 1***

Se coloco duas controller, a minha view se perde. A Controller atual para receber o `JSON` é essa:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TipoContatoOperadoraController', ['$scope', '$http', TipoContatoOperadoraController])

function TipoContatoOperadoraController($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('http://localhost:7216/api/estruturaOrganizacional/tiposContatoOperadora')
        .success(function (data) {

            $scope.listaTipoContatoOperadora = data.items;
        })
        .error(function () {
            //$scope.dt = 'Teste: ' + $scope.data;
            $scope.erro = 'Erro: Não foi possível carregar a lista do tipo de contato das operadoras.';
        });

}
```

Há como fazer nessa controller a paginação? Tá osso.

***EDIÇÃO 2***

Ficou assim minha controller e mesmo assim não pagina:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TipoContatoOperadoraController', ['$scope', '$http', TipoContatoOperadoraController])

function TipoContatoOperadoraController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.filteredTodos = []
   , $scope.currentPage = 1
   , $scope.numPerPage = 10
   , $scope.maxSize = 5;

    $http.get('http://localhost:7216/api/estruturaOrganizacional/tiposContatoOperadora')
        .success(function (data) {

            $scope.listaTipoContatoOperadora = data.items;

            $scope.makePagina = function (data) {
                $scope.pagina = [];
                for (i = 1; i <= data.items.lehgth; i++) {
                    $scope.msg = "Teste " + i;
                    $scope.pagina.push({ text: "Teste " + i, done: false });
                }
            };

            $scope.makePagina();

            $scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function () {
                var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                $scope.filteredPagina = $scope.pagina.slice(begin, end);
            });

        })
        .error(function () {
            //$scope.dt = 'Teste: ' + $scope.data;
            $scope.erro = 'Erro: Não foi possível carregar a lista do tipo de contato das operadoras.';
        });

}
```

***EDIÇÃO 3***

Fiz essa alteração e funcionou. O que faltou foi o AngularJS-UI e o CSS ou Bootstrap, montar a navegação das páginas, mas isso funcionou.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:7216/api/estruturaOrganizacional/tiposContatoOperadora')
        .success(function (data) {

            $scope.filteredTodos = []
              , $scope.currentPage = 1
              , $scope.maxSize = 5
              , $scope.numPerPage = data.items.length / $scope.maxSize;

            $scope.listaTipoContatoOperadora = data.items;
            var t = data.items.length;
            console.log(t);

            $scope.makePagina = function () {
                $scope.pagina = [];
                for (i = 1; i <= data.items.length; i++) {
                    $scope.pagina.push({ text: "Página " + i, done: false });
                }
            };

            $scope.makePagina();

            $scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function () {
                var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                $scope.filteredPagina = $scope.pagina.slice(begin, end);
            });

        })
        .error(function () {
            //$scope.dt = 'Teste: ' + $scope.data;
            $scope.erro = 'Erro: Não foi possível carregar a lista do tipo de contato das operadoras.';
        });
```

***EDIÇÃO 4***

Consegui fazer o slice com esse código. Só não estou conseguindo trazer os botões de navegação entre as páginas:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TipoContatoOperadoraController', ['$scope', '$http', TipoContatoOperadoraController])

function TipoContatoOperadoraController($scope, $http) {



    $http.get('http://localhost:7216/api/estruturaOrganizacional/tiposContatoOperadora')
        .success(function (data) {

            $scope.filteredPagina = []
              , $scope.currentPage = 1
              , $scope.maxSize = 5
              , $scope.numPerPage = data.items.length / $scope.maxSize;

            $scope.listaTipoContatoOperadora = data.items;

            $scope.makePagina = function () {
                $scope.app = [];
                for (i = 1; i <= data.items.length; i++) {
                    $scope.app.push({ text: "Página " + i, done: false });
                }
            };

            $scope.makePagina();

            $scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function () {
                var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                $scope.filteredPagina = $scope.listaTipoContatoOperadora.slice(begin, end);
            });

        })
        .error(function () {
            //$scope.dt = 'Teste: ' + $scope.data;
            $scope.erro = 'Erro: Não foi possível carregar a lista do tipo de contato das operadoras.';
        });

}
```

E minha view(apenas as TD's) ficou assim:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="lista in filteredPagina">
    <td>{{ lista.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ lista.nome }}</td>
    <td>{{ lista.tipoContato }}</td>
    <td>{{ lista.dataUltimaAtualizacao }}</td>
    <td>{{ lista.loginUltimaAtualizacao }}</td>
</tr>
```

Apenas alterei o foreach para a(s) página(s) filtrada(s)

Comment: Pra isso ficar "certo" vc tem que paginar os dados na sua consulta com o banco

Comment: @DiegoAugusto, o `AngularJS` não faz um slice do `JSON`?

Comment: Qual erro você recebe em data.items.length?

Comment: Agora não deu erro, mas nada acontece. Eu fiz duas controllers e o sistema não está permitindo isso. Quando eu coloco duas controllers, me dá pau, não sobe o JSON. Se retiro a controller da paginação aí funfa.

Comment: @pnet Faz, mas vc não vai ganhar nada em termos de performance, pois se tiver uma tabela no banco com muitos registros a consulta irá demorar da mesma forma

Comment: Entendi, no momento é mais aprendizado mesmo. Até semana passada nem sabia o que era o AngulaJS. Gostaria de fazer de uma forma, aprender e depois sim, ir vendo outras formas e aprendendo.

Comment: Coloquei a paginação dentro da controller do json e me dá esse erro: `angular.js:13708TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
    at m.$scope.makePagina (TipoContatoOperadoraController.js:20)`

Comment: Funcionou que eu quero dizer é mostrar os textos das páginas, mas ainda tenho muito trabalho a fazer. Mas fazer outro post agora para o slice do JSON.

Comment: @pnet, tente manter as suas perguntas mais atômicas, se a sua duvida inicial era sobre como dividir os dados na tela, porém se ao resolver este problema apareceu um problema relacionado as ações da paginação, então aceite a resposta que lhe ajudou a identificar o problema e poste a alteração necessária, por fim crie uma nova pergunta com o problema decorrente do inicial, e de preferencia poste um link para a pergunta original.

Comment: @TobyMosque, então foi o que eu fiz. Fui fazendo as edições, para mostrar a evolução que eu fui obtendo. Tanto que eu abri outro post. Às vezes fazemos comentários, que realmente foge da pergunta original, dado ao englobamento das respostas e/ou sugestões que vão aparecendo, mas percebendo isso, fiz outro post e encerrei esse com a solução postada. Na resposta do OnoSendai, não entendi bem o que ele quis dizer, razão pela qual não marquei a resposta, apenas isso. Mas de qualquer forma agradeço as respostas e o seu comentário, que é sempre de bom grado. Ao OnoSendai, principalmente agradeço.

Answer (score 3):

Você tem algumas possibilidades.

- **Dados completos, paginação no Angular**: Seu endpoint retornará a coleção completa de dados. Excelente método para coleções pequenas, péssimo para grandes.
- **Paginação no servidor, requisição de páginas via angular**: Tanto a experiência do usuário quanto o banco de dados podem sofrer degradação com a quantidade extra de troca de dados.
- **Híbrido**: Gere um conjunto de páginas de dados a partir do servidor, e deixe o controle de conteúdo do lado do Angular. Método mais complexo, porém mais eficiente em termos de consumo de banco e experiência de usuário.

O seu caso corresponde ao primeiro tipo.

Na sua primeira pergunta o laço `for` está sendo utilizado apenas para a criação de um array de exemplo (`$scope.pagina`). Este array então recebe 1000 unidades.

Na sua segunda pergunta `$scope.numPerPage` significa quantos registros devem existir por página. Se o valor for 10, então um conjunto de 35 registros poderá popular 4 páginas (3 contendo 10 registos mais uma página parcial com 5): 10 + 10 + 10 + 5 = 35.

Comment: OnoSendai, obrigado , mas é o seguinte. Lá tem um For de 1000, que foi o exemplo baixado. O que eu quero é substituir o 1000 pelo meus registros JSON que o REST me disponibiliza, Isso é que eu não sei fazer. Lá está 10, porque no exemplo baixado o autor fixou. O que eu gostaria é de deixar dinâmico em bloco de X registros. Essa é minha dúvida que não consigo andar. Essa é minha segunda semana com AngularJS.

Comment: Vou encerrar o post colocando o meu código referente a Edição 4 como resposta e abrir outro referente aos botões de navegação. São duas coisas distintas, não totalmente, mas vou separar as coisas.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer o slice com esse código. Só não estou conseguindo trazer os botões de navegação entre as páginas:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TipoContatoOperadoraController', ['$scope', '$http', TipoContatoOperadoraController])

function TipoContatoOperadoraController($scope, $http) {



    $http.get('http://localhost:7216/api/estruturaOrganizacional/tiposContatoOperadora')
        .success(function (data) {

            $scope.filteredPagina = []
              , $scope.currentPage = 1
              , $scope.maxSize = 5
              , $scope.numPerPage = data.items.length / $scope.maxSize;

            $scope.listaTipoContatoOperadora = data.items;

            $scope.makePagina = function () {
                $scope.app = [];
                for (i = 1; i <= data.items.length; i++) {
                    $scope.app.push({ text: "Página " + i, done: false });
                }
            };

            $scope.makePagina();

            $scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function () {
                var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                $scope.filteredPagina = $scope.listaTipoContatoOperadora.slice(begin, end);
            });

        })
        .error(function () {
            //$scope.dt = 'Teste: ' + $scope.data;
            $scope.erro = 'Erro: Não foi possível carregar a lista do tipo de contato das operadoras.';
        });

}
```

E minha view(apenas as TD's) ficou assim:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="lista in filteredPagina">
    <td>{{ lista.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ lista.nome }}</td>
    <td>{{ lista.tipoContato }}</td>
    <td>{{ lista.dataUltimaAtualizacao }}</td>
    <td>{{ lista.loginUltimaAtualizacao }}</td>
</tr>
```

Apenas alterei o foreach para a(s) página(s) filtrada(s)